# Разбить строку на символы

Tags: c#

Можно ли в языке C# когда вводишь строку "string", например: "Собака" - разделить его на буквы "C", "о", "б", "а", "к", "а". Я знаю по функцию "Split", но там надо задавать место разделение, а мне нужно прям каждый символ и пробел тоже!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В классе `string` есть специальный метод `ToCharArray`, который возвращает массив символов. Также `string` реализует `IEnumerable<char>`, поэтому мы можем воспользоваться методом расширения из Linq `ToArray`. Выбирайте какой нравится (но подозреваю, что первый может работать быстрее, т.к. строке известна ее длина, а второй более универсальный метод и работает для любых последовательностей):

```
string s = "string";
char[] a = s.ToCharArray();
char[] b = s.ToArray();
```

Ну а если вам не нужно изменять данные, а только читать - можно воспользоваться индексатором: `Console.WriteLine(s[0]);`

Если вы хотите посимвольно отредактировать строку, то получите массив символов, как написано выше, отредактируйте любые элементы в нем и получите строку из конечного массива (у `string` есть конструктор, принимающий массив символов):

```
string s2 = new string(a);
```

Вместо массива можно использовать класс `StringBuilder` - он представляет изменяемую строку, индексатор у него поддерживает как чтение, так и запись:

```
string s1 = "string";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s1);
sb[0] = 'b';
sb[1] = 'o';
string s2 = sb.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(s2);
```

Comment: или `s[i]` тоже сработает - обращение сразу как будто к массиву (индексатор есть)

Comment: @dgzargo, ну я, вроде, так и написал

Comment: индексатор у строки `string s = "string";` `char c = s[0];`

Answer (score 5):

Как вариант:

```
string str = "Собака";

foreach(char c in str)
{
   Console.WriteLine(c);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: По сути сам `string` содержит в себе всю информацию. Достаточно написать `str[1]` - для получения определенного символа, либо пройтись циклом по самому значению `(foreach(char c in srt)`. В связи с этим `.ToCharArray()` порой бывает лишним (зависит от задачи). Хотя там внутренняя кухня языка C#, я в подробности не вдавался, может при компиляции и то и то будет одинаковым.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вообще да, вы правы, что-то не подумал сразу) Подправлю