# Как разделить переменную типа string в string[]

Tags: c#, массивы, строки

Есть строка вводимая пользователем

```
Console.Writeline("Введите пример: ");
string ST = Consile.Readline();
```

Нужно разделить её по символам и поместить в массив.
Как можно реализовать?

Comment: По одному символу что ли?

Comment: Да! Ну как массив.

Comment: var arr = ST.Split('.');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

```
string[] array = ST.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Но для начала можете попробовать работать непосредственно с символами (char), а не строками:

```
char[] chars = ST.ToCharArray();
```

Comment: var array = ST.ToCharArray() - не проще ли?

Comment: Уверены, что это сработает? ;) Ах, ну массив char, конечно. Автору, вроде, нужен массив строк...

Comment: ну я только в обявлении переменной профакапился)

Comment: Ну дык... Но про char[] я уже добавил на всякий случай

Comment: Да заработает. Даже просто ToArray сработает как надо.

Comment: `ToArray` скорее всего менее эффективен.

Comment: Не работает! Я наверное неправильно вопрос задал. Нужно к примеру ввести (5+6-3*4)  через `readline()`, после чего, весь этот пример разделить на отдельные символы с которыми можно взаимодействовать по индексу.

Comment: @j.Atisto и что конкретно не работает? `string ST = Consile.Readline(); char[] chars = ST.ToCharArray();` далее работаете с массивом `chars` как хотите: `chars[3] = 'x';`

Comment: @Андрей NOP Я пробовал через цикл for там не сработал почему то???!  Хотя должно! Буду думать. А, если просто по индексу работает. Спасибо! Буду думать дальше!

Comment: @j.Atisto, строка неизменяема! Посмотрите этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/788515/218063

Comment: @Андрей NOP Спасибо!